# Closure and Possible Deletion: How can I tactfully write that I haven't received a reply?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I've improved [How can I tactfully write that I haven't received a reply?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/110418/22656). Can it please be reopened? But why are there 2 votes for deletion?

Answer (score 4):

And it's currently at -7 votes, so won't be visible to the front page even if it was opened.

The problem here is that there's no context - you're simply stating that emails are going unanswered.  You've not stated the importance of the emails, whether the emails have stated that you need a response in a timely manner, or even what the purpose of the emails are.

Without any background information, this is impossible to answer.

I don't mean to be patronizing here, but do a little role-play here.  Pretend that you aren't you and read your question from someone else's perspective.  Is there enough information here for someone to answer the question?

You're clearly no stranger to Stack Exchange and you've gain good reputation on other sites and should understand the need for clear questions.

Comment: Thanks, especially your last two paras. I edited the post now. Better?